# Skip includes from documentation

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen for my c++ library project. I would like to skip header include information  with dependency graph from documentation. How to achieve that?

UPD

Need to omit:
[image]

Comment: You can use the \cond and \endcond commands to conditionally exclude specific parts of the code from being processed by Doxygen.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What do you exactly mean with "skip header include information with dependency graph from documentation" what do you want to skip?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the setting `DIRECTORY_GRAPH`, `SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES`, `INCLUDE_PATH`.

Comment: @albert I have updated question body with picture that shows info to skip

Comment: I had a quick look at the code but as far as I can see: at the moment there is no possibility to skip this graph. (open question remains: Which version of doxygen are you using?).

Comment: I'm using Doxygen version 1.8.17

Comment: If it is not possible to exclude include info then how to deal in situation when I would like to provide library exported function list without revealing code internals and details?

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.17 is already a bit older December 27, 2019 the current doxygen version is 1.9.6

Comment: In my previous comment about the settings I overlooked in the overview I mad the settings `INCLUDE_GRAPH` and `INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH`, with setting these to `NO` is should be possible.