# Skip functions without doxygen comments from documentation

Tags: c++, doxygen

Code below shows cpp file that contains two function `add` (has doxygen comments) and `showInt` (no doxygen comments). Currently both function appears in Doxygen documentation. Is it possible to ask doxygen to include only functions that contains doxygen comments?

```
/**
 * @{ \name utils API
 * \brief API provides math functions
 */

#include <iostream>

 /**
  * \brief Adds two numbers.
  *
  * This function takes two numbers, adds them, and then returns the result.
  *
  * \param x The first number to add.
  * \param y The second number to add.
  * \return The sum of the two numbers.
  */
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

void showInt(int value)
{
    std::cout << "value=" << value;
}
```

Doxygen version 1.8.17

doxygen -x Doxyfile

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
PROJECT_NAME           = "Kyle's Doxygen Test"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = "This is just a test of Doxygen"
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = NO
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = NO
```

Comment: One of [these methods](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_code), perhaps?

Comment: "include only functions that have Doxygen comments" is actually the default behavior.  You must have `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` in your configuration, forcing documentation of functions without comments.  Remove that, or change it to `EXTRACT_ALL = NO` (which is the default)

Comment: Missing doxygen version (will be 1.8.17 see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76064601/1657886. We need also the settings you used (i.e. the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`). The remark from @BenVoigt is correct (he just beat me to it).

Comment: @BenVoigt if I put `EXTRACT_ALL = NO` it generates documents only from header file and I need to include cpp files too.

Comment: @vico: Put a `\file` comment on each source file.  Or use pages and modules to group the items.  (Or both)